# Discrete Systems - fish population modelling question on derivation of the model

Tags: mathematical-modeling, nonlinear-system

I am currently reading 'Introduction to Non-Linear Systems' by J Berry and on page 112 there is an exercise (question 5) which I don't understand, it is:

> The population of fish in a large lake has been stable for some time.
>   Prior to this situation the population was decreasing from an
>   initially relatively high level. When the population was 4000 the
>   proportionate birth rate was 10% and the proportionate death rate was
>   70%. When the population was 3000 the proportionate birth rate was 30%
>   and the proportionate death rate was 60%. This population model also
>   has the following assumptions:
>
> - there is no exploitation and no restocking
> - the proportionate birth rate is a decreasing linear function of the population
> - the proportionate death rate is an increasing linear function of population
>
> Show that the model based on these assumptions and the above data
>   predicts that the populations falls according to the logistic model
>   and find the equilibrium population size

Now the book has given the following solution:

$$P_{n+1}-P_n = \left (0.6 - 3 \times 10^{-4}P_n \right)P_n$$ and that the stable equilibrium is 2000 fish.

Now my question is how is this model derived from the data in the question? And how is the equilibrium calculated?

I think perhaps the solution above is using the conservation law which is $$accumulation = input - output$$ But I can't get from the numbers in the question to a formula like that above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has the form $P_{n+1}-P_n=r(P_n)P_n$ where $r(P)$, positive or negative, is the reproduction rate at population $P$. One is given that $r(4000)=10\%-70\%$ and $r(3000)=30\%-60\%$. The linearity assumptions imply that $r(P)=b-aP$ for some $a$ and $b$ independent of $P$. Solving the system of two equations $b-4000a=-0.6$ and $b-3000a=-0.3$ yields $a=0.0003$ and $b=0.6$, as desired.

The points $P_*$ of equilibrium are when $P_n=P_*$ yields $P_{n+1}=P_*$. Here, the equilibrium you are asked to detect is when $r(P_*)=0$, that is, at $P_*=b/a=2000$, but note that there is a second one at $P=0$. The next question in the exercise might be to show that $P_*=2000$ is attractive while $0$ is repulsive.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I can follow your argument and see how to obtain the solutions.